# Authorization failure TIdHTTP over HTTPS

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

I want to approach the Exchange webservice and handle XML SOAP composition (request) and parsing (response) myself.
Therefore, THTPPRIO seems a bit overkill.

I'm trying TIdHTTP but I'm stuck on the authentication; using Delphi XE2 update 4 with Indy 10.5.8.0

Here's the code:

```
idHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('SOAPAction','"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/ResolveNames"');
IdHTTP1.Post('https://webmail.mailserver.nl/ews/exchange.asmx',TSRequest,TSResponse);
```

- TSRequest,TSResponse are UTF-8 TStringStreams, TSRequest contains the
  entire SOAP envelope
- IdHTTP1.IOHandler is set to a
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL, per [this advice](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=77443)
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Intercept is linked to a TIdLogDebug so
  that I can debug what's going on
- OpenSSL DLLs are present in the DLL search path
- EWS wants NTLM validation; TIdNTLMAuthentication is in the uses clause; I have
  set idHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication=false, Username and
  Password filled in
- The IdHTTP1.OnSelectAuthorization event confirms the NTLM auth
  (parameters AuthenticationClass = TIdSSPINTLMAuthentication, and
  the AuthInfo TIdHeaderList contains'Negotiate', 'NTLM')
- There is no proxy. I proxied through [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what's
  going on, but that makes no difference.

I also tried setting user/PW run-time:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1Authorization(Sender: TObject; Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Authentication.Username := 'bob@domain.nl';
  Authentication.Password := 'password';
  Handled := true;
end;
```

Sent HTTP (from TIdLogDebug.OnSend) starts with:

```
POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 562
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/ResolveNames"
Host: webmail.mailserver.nl
Accept: text/html, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate, identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)


<soapenv:Envelope
```

Received HTTP (from TIdLogDebug.OnReceive) is

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=0157734634ba4a0fa3a7d0d8efb602f2; expires=Tue, 12-Nov-2013 13:38:56 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2012 13:38:56 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

The TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnStatusInfo event logs

```
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write client hello A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server hello A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server certificate A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server done A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write client key exchange A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write change cipher spec A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write finished A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 flush data"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read finished A"
SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
Cipher: name = AES128-SHA; description = AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
; bits = 128; version = TLSv1/SSLv3;
```

What I miss in the outgoing HTTP is a line like (as e.g. generated by [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org)):

```
"Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAANQIIIBQAFAAyAAAAEgASACAAAABWAE0ASgBBAE4AVABUADcANABUAEkATQBFAFQARQBMAEwAQgBWAA==[\r][\n]"
```

Maybe I don't specify username/PW in the correct place?

Added 13 Nov after Remy's initial answer:

For comparison, I called the webservice from SOAPUI and this shows **6 packets** going over the line, with twice a response UnAuthorized.

```
>> "POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
>> "SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/ResolveNames"[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 548[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: webmail.timetellbv.nl[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> "<soapenv:Envelope [\n]"
[snip]
>> "</soapenv:Envelope>[\n]"
>> "[\n]"

<< "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
<< "Cache-Control: private[\r][\n]"
<< "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5[\r][\n]"
<< "X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727[\r][\n]"
<< "Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=a29f10ca2a6d484ea276737e87d8e733; expires=Wed, 13-Nov-2013 10:47:33 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly[\r][\n]"
<< "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate[\r][\n]"
<< "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM[\r][\n]"
<< "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
<< "Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 10:47:33 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"

>> "POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
>> "SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/ResolveNames"[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 548[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: webmail.timetellbv.nl[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
>> "Cookie: exchangecookie=a29f10ca2a6d484ea276737e87d8e733[\r][\n]"
>> "Cookie2: $Version=1[\r][\n]"
>> "Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAANQIIIBQAFAAyAAAAEgASACAAAABWAE0ASgBBAE4AVABUADcANABUAEkATQBFAFQARQBMAEwAQgBWAA==[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> "<soapenv:Envelope [\n]"
[snip]
>> "</soapenv:Envelope>[\n]"
>> "[\n]"

<< "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
<< "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5[\r][\n]"
<< "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAFAAUADgAAAA1AokilFuJDu09j+sAAAAAAAAAAMAAwABMAAAABgGxHQAAAA9UAEkATQBFAFQARQBMAEwAQgBWAAIAFABUAEkATQBFAFQARQBMAEwAQgBWAAEAHABUAFQARQBYAEMASABBAE4ARwBFADIAMAAxADAABAAaAHQAaQBtAGUAdABlAGwAbABiAHYALgBuAGwAAwA4AFQAVABFAFgAQwBIAEEATgBHAEUAMgAwADEAMAAuAHQAaQBtAGUAdABlAGwAbABiAHYALgBuAGwABQAaAHQAaQBtAGUAdABlAGwAbABiAHYALgBuAGwABwAIADs8RkmMwc0BAAAAAA==[\r][\n]"
<< "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate[\r][\n]"
<< "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
<< "Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 10:47:33 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"

>> "POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
>> "SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/ResolveNames"[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 548[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: webmail.timetellbv.nl[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
>> "Cookie: exchangecookie=a29f10ca2a6d484ea276737e87d8e733[\r][\n]"
>> "Cookie2: $Version=1[\r][\n]"
>> "Authorization: NTLM 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[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> "<soapenv:Envelope [\n]"
[snip]
>> "</soapenv:Envelope>[\n]"
>> "[\n]"

<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
<< "Cache-Control: private[\r][\n]"
<< "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
<< "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5[\r][\n]"
<< "X-EwsPerformanceData: RpcC=2;RpcL=0;LdapC=1;LdapL=0;[\r][\n]"
<< "X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727[\r][\n]"
<< "Persistent-Auth: true[\r][\n]"
<< "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
<< "Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 10:47:33 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
<< "877[\r][\n]"
<< "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
[snip]
<< "</s:Envelope>"
<< "[\r][\n]"
<< "0[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
```

So from Delphi I only see the first 2 packets exchanging. Strange thing is, if I click my 'Test' button **again** the exchange seems to continue???:

Request:

```
POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 562
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/ResolveNames"
Host: webmail.timetellbv.nl
Accept: text/html, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate, identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbEdAAAADw==


<soapenv:Envelope 
[snip]
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAFAAUADgAAAAFgomiqrTrZnWjEdQAAAAAAAAAAMAAwABMAAAABgGxHQAAAA9UAEkATQBFAFQARQBMAEwAQgBWAAIAFABUAEkATQBFAFQARQBMAEwAQgBWAAEAHABUAFQARQBYAEMASABBAE4ARwBFADIAMAAxADAABAAaAHQAaQBtAGUAdABlAGwAbABiAHYALgBuAGwAAwA4AFQAVABFAFgAQwBIAEEATgBHAEUAMgAwADEAMAAuAHQAaQBtAGUAdABlAGwAbABiAHYALgBuAGwABQAaAHQAaQBtAGUAdABlAGwAbABiAHYALgBuAGwABwAIAOZ26g+Owc0BAAAAAA==
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=0c8362d303d742c6aae98bd1df574a4d; expires=Wed, 13-Nov-2013 11:00:16 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 11:00:15 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

And if I click my Test button a **third time** I get an actual EIdHTTPProtocolException and this data exchange:

Request:

```
POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 562
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/ResolveNames"
Host: webmail.timetellbv.nl
Accept: text/html, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate, identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)
Authorization: NTLM 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


<soapenv:Envelope 
[snip]
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=2a4876f8adeb425384fb370cafa61ee6; expires=Wed, 13-Nov-2013 11:25:11 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 11:25:11 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Thanks
Jan

Comment: I have abandoned this approach in favor of using THTTPReqResp - that is much easier. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345540/how-to-add-overwrite-a-http-header-using-thttpreqresp Still curious for the solution though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically an `Authorization` header is not sent until the server asks for it via a 401 reply.  You won't see it on the initial request, but `TIdHTTP` should be sending new requests with an `Authorization` header after processing the 401 reply.  In any case, you should be using the `TIdHTTP.Request.Username` and `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` properties to set the initial credentials, then use the `OnAuthorization` event to provide new credentials as needed.