# SOAP message - Add authentication in http header

Tags: delphi, http, soap, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have to send a SOAP message to a WebService that needs BASIC authentication in the HTTP request, but I can't find a way to do it.

After searching, I found some solutions and workarounds, but none of them worked.

Here's my code:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.HTTPRIOHTTPWebNode1BeforePost(
 const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
var
 UserName: string;
 PassWord: string;
begin

UserName := 'aaa';
Password := 'bbb';

if not InternetSetOption(Data,
                  INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME,
                  PChar(UserName),
                  Length(UserName)) then
 raise Exception(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));

if not InternetSetOption(Data,
                  INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD,
                  PChar(Password),
                  Length(Password)) then
 raise Exception(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));


end;
```

I tried setting the Username and Password in the `HTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode`, but it ignores them, and it doesn't rise the exceptions.

The WebService keeps telling me that credentials are missing.

I managed to do it in C#:

```cs
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
    Byte[] credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("aaa:bbb");
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Basic {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer)));
    return request;
}
```

but I can't find a way to do it in Delphi.

Am I missing something, or am I doing it wrong?

I use Delphi XE8 with FireMonkey.

Comment: I think you are supposed to use OnBeforePost handlers so you are on the right track. Are you following forum posts? Is the handler even invoked? Add logging. https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=681097

Comment: BTW Do you have tools to see what's going over the line? I use Fiddler in Delphi to see what's happening and SOAPUI to test out calls 'as they should be'. Comparing the two often helps, here's an example of using these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345474/authorization-failure-tidhttp-over-https

Comment: Here's another BeforePost example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345540/how-to-add-overwrite-a-http-header-using-thttpreqresp

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I managed to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I did it thanks to the comments.

```
procedure TMyForm.HTTPRIOHTTPWebNode1BeforePost(
 const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
var
 auth: String;
begin

  auth := 'Authorization: Basic ' + idEncoderMIME1.EncodeString('aaa:bbb' );
  HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, PChar(auth), Length(auth), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);

end;
```

I just add to the header 'Authorization: Basic ' + username:password encoded.

Actually I only did what I was doing in c#, but I couldn't figure it out before.

Thanks

Comment: What is data type of object idEncoderMIME1 ? Where is this object created ?

Comment: How can I handle soap server side ?

Comment: @truthseeker `idEncoderMIME1` is of type `TIdEncoderMIME`, which is a class in Indy, which comes pre-installed with the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

In newer version of Delphi (before 10.3 Rio)

```
procedure TClientSOAP.DoHTTPWebNodeBeforePost(
  const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
var
  auth: String;
begin
  auth := 'Authorization: Basic ' + TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(FUserName + ':' + FPassword);
  HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, PChar(auth), Length(auth), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
end;
```

With 10.3 Rio you have to use mjn42 answer even if you have proxy

Comment: How can I handle soap server side ?

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP Basic Authentication, this code (placed before calling the SOAP service) should work:

```
HTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.UserName := 'aaa';
HTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.Password := 'bbb';
```

instead of the `TMyForm.HTTPRIOHTTPWebNode1BeforePost` event handler