# Delphi - Authorization TIdHttp fails over HTTP proxy

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, indy10, delphi-xe6

I'm using Delphi XE 6 and TIdHttp component(Indy 10.6.0.5122) and trying to consume a SOAP service - http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx over a http proxy (CCProxy - http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/). The issue is that at the first attempt to connect to the webservice I receive an "Unauthorized" respone:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head><body><h1>Unauthorized ...</h1>
<h2>IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.:61295<br>
MAC Address: <br>
Server Time: 2014-11-18 14:19:00<br>
Auth Result: </h2></body></html>
```

I've linked an IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL and IdLogDebug1 components to IdHttp in order to debug the issue.

Logs of the operations performed

```
***********************IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1Status 
Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

***********************IdLogDebug1Send 
POST http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 388
SOAPAction: http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry
Host: www.webservicex.net
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)



***********************IdLogDebug1Send 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCitiesByCountry xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <CountryName>Romania</CountryName>
    </GetCitiesByCountry>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

***********************IdLogDebug1Receive 
HTTP/1.0 407 Unauthorized
Server: Proxy
Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="CCProxy Authorization"
Cache-control: no-cache

<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head><body><h1>Unauthorized ...</h1>
<h2>IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61295<br>
MAC Address: <br>
Server Time: 2014-11-18 14:19:00<br>
Auth Result: </h2></body></html>

***********************IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1Status 
Disconnected.
```

Now, what is interesting is that if I'm trying again to call the webservice everything works correctly. Log of the operations:

```
***********************IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1Status 
Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

***********************IdLogDebug1Send 
POST http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 388
SOAPAction: http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry
Host: www.webservicex.net
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)
Proxy-Authorization: Basic YW1ibzphbWJvIQ==



***********************IdLogDebug1Send 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCitiesByCountry xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <CountryName>Romania</CountryName>
    </GetCitiesByCountry>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

***********************IdLogDebug1Receive 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 2456


***********************IdLogDebug1Receive 
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 12:26:21 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetCitiesByCountryResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET"><GetCitiesByCountryResult>&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;Country&gt;Romania&lt;/Country&gt;
    &lt;City&gt;Arad&lt;/City&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;Country&gt;Romania&lt;/Country&gt;
    &lt;City&gt;Bacau&lt;/City&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  ......
```

And the response it's correct.

Code of the application

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, Soap.SOAPHTTPTrans,
  IdAuthentication, IdHeaderList, IdIntercept, IdLogBase, IdLogDebug,
  IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL
  ,IdGlobal;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    Button1: TButton;
    HTTPReqResp1: THTTPReqResp;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    IdLogDebug1: TIdLogDebug;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdHTTP1ProxyAuthorization(Sender: TObject;
      Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1StatusInfo(const AMsg: string);
    procedure IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1Status(ASender: TObject;
      const AStatus: TIdStatus; const AStatusText: string);
    procedure IdLogDebug1Receive(ASender: TIdConnectionIntercept;
      var ABuffer: TIdBytes);
    procedure IdLogDebug1Send(ASender: TIdConnectionIntercept;
      var ABuffer: TIdBytes);
    procedure IdHTTP1Authorization(Sender: TObject;
      Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  postData: TMemoryStream;
begin
  postData := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    postData.LoadFromFile('..\..\soap1.1.txt');
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
    IdHTTP1.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['SOAPAction'] := 'http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry';
    IdHTTP1.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
    IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions := IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions + [hoKeepOrigProtocol];
    Memo1.Lines.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx', postData);
  finally
    postData.Free;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 with IdHTTP1.ProxyParams do
  begin
    ProxyServer := 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
    ProxyPort := 808;
    ProxyUsername := 'User-001';
    ProxyPassword := 'User-001!';
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1Authorization(Sender: TObject;
  Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
//
  Authentication.Username := 'User-001';
  Authentication.Password := 'User-001!';
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1ProxyAuthorization(Sender: TObject;
  Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
//
// Authentication.Username := 'User-001';
// Authentication.Password := 'User-001!';
// Handled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdLogDebug1Receive(ASender: TIdConnectionIntercept;
  var ABuffer: TIdBytes);
begin
 Memo2.Lines.Add(#13#10+'***********************IdLogDebug1Receive '+#13#10+BytesToString(ABuffer))
end;

procedure TForm1.IdLogDebug1Send(ASender: TIdConnectionIntercept;
  var ABuffer: TIdBytes);
begin
 Memo2.Lines.Add(#13#10+'***********************IdLogDebug1Send '+#13#10+BytesToString(ABuffer))
end;

procedure TForm1.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1Status(ASender: TObject;
  const AStatus: TIdStatus; const AStatusText: string);
begin
Memo2.Lines.Add(#13#10+'***********************IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1Status '+#13#10+AStatusText)
end;

procedure TForm1.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1StatusInfo(const AMsg: string);
begin
Memo2.Lines.Add(#13#10+'***********************IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1StatusInfo '+#13#10+AMsg)
end;

end.
```

How should I make the authentication in order to work from the first attempt?

PS : I've already read this question - [Authorization failure TIdHTTP over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345474/authorization-failure-tidhttp-over-https).

ANSWER : based on the indications of Remy Lebeau problem was solved by setting up the

> OnProxySelectAuthorization

event and add the **hoInProcessAuth** to the

> IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions

Comment: If I may ask, why not consume the webservice with THTTPRIO?

Comment: I've tried to consume the webservice with THttpRio, but delphi SOAP implementation is buggy when a http Proxy exists between the client and webservice, and when both require authentication...

Comment: Thank you downvoter. You should also provide me a reason for -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have added the `IdAuthentication` unit to your `uses` clause so `TIdHTTP` can process `Proxy-Authorization` headers in a 407 reply, and also make sure you have a `TIdHTTP.OnProxyAuthorization` event handler assigned (even if it just returns `Handled:=True`) otherwise `TIdHTTP` will not attempt proxy authorization while processing a 407 reply, even though you have provided a username/password in the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` property.

What is most likely happening is that the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams.Authentication` property is initially nil during the first request, and gets filled in with a `TIdBasicAuthentication` object while processing the 407 reply, but a missing `OnProxyAuthorization` event handler causes `TIdHTTP` to skip authorization, and then the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams.Authentication` property is not nil anymore when the second request is made, so it attempts authorization at that time.

Skipping proxy authorization if the `TIdHTTP.OnProxyAuthorization` event is not assigned appears to be a bug, IMHO.  By comparison, the `TIdHTTP.OnAuthorization` event can be unassigned as long as a non-empty value is assigned to the `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` property.  I have now updated `TIdHTTP` with similar logic for the `OnProxyAuthorization` event regarding the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams.Password` property.

So, either update to the latest SVN snapshot, or just assign a `TIdHTTP.OnProxyAuthorization` event handler, then you should be OK:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1ProxyAuthorization(Sender: TObject; Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  // prompt the user for username/password (optional) and store them
  // in the Authentication.Username and Authentication.Password
  // properties, respectively. By default, they are initialized with
  // the current values of the ProxyParams.UserName and
  // ProxyParams.Password properties...
  Handled := True;
end;
```

Comment: I've added the event as you said, but the result is the same even the AuthenticationClass is not nil. IdHTTP1SelectProxyAuthorization(Sender: TObject;  var AuthenticationClass: TIdAuthenticationClass;...);

 if AuthenticationClass = nil then
  showmessage('nil');
end;

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that adding on `OnProxySelectAuthorization` event handler would fix it. I was suggesting that adding the `IdAuthentication` unit to the `uses` clause should fix it. But there appears to be a `OnProxyAuthorization` bug in play. I updated my answer with details.

Comment: It was already added on the uses clause. I will try your update, and accept the answer if it is correct.

Comment: I've uncommented the code from OnProxyAuthorization and delete the code from SelectAuthorization and SelectProxyAuthorization, but the result is the same. First time I get an Unauthorized and second time it is working...

Comment: Make sure the `hoInProcessAuth` flag is enabled in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` properties. If it is, and authorization is still not working, then please update your question with the latest code and HTTP trace. When `TIdHTTP` sees a 407 from a proxy, it should be attempting authorization right away. I don't have an HTTP proxy that I can test this with myself.